# Odoo difference in Javascript extend and include

Tags: javascript, class, include, odoo, odoo-10

In Odoo one can `extend` or `include` on a class (in Javascript). What is the difference in Odoo between `extend` and `include`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you `extend`, instances from the parent class remain untouched, but instances from the new child class will have the extended features.

OTOH, when you `include`, you are adding the new features to the prototype of the parent class, which means that automatically all instances of such class include the extended behavior.

---

You know, JS works with prototypes; i wrote about *class* and *instance* just to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thank You for the answer! :)

Comment: "include" is a very powerfull feature that should never be included. ;-) 
If two modules take a common parent to create their widgets, One could change the behavior of the other, that was made only knowing parent.

Comment: Actually the point is that you should always `return this._super.apply(this, arguments)` to avoid that problem. But the whole odoo ecosystem drains its power from monkey-patching itself, so `include` instead that never being used, it should be used wisely.